# jackson Include.NOT_NULL on field not working

Tags: java, jackson, lombok

Using `JsonInclude(content=Include.NON_NULL)` (or actually any other `JsonInclude` options) seems to have no effect on serialization of my objects. Consider this test:

```
public class JsonTest {
    @Data
    @JsonInclude(content=Include.ALWAYS)
    static class TestObj {
        String fieldVisible = "a";
        String fieldVisibleNull = null;
        @JsonInclude(content=Include.NON_NULL)
        String fieldInvisible = null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = mapper.writerFor(TestObj.class).writeValueAsString(new TestObj());
        if (json.contains("fieldInvisible")) {
            System.err.println(json);
            throw new RuntimeException("null field written even though it shouldn't be");
        }
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
{"fieldVisible":"a","fieldVisibleNull":null,"fieldInvisible":null}
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: null field written even though it shouldn't be
    at my.package.JsonTest.main(JsonTest.java:57)
```

**What am I missing?** What don't I understand?

Comment: From what I gather you should be using the `value` attribute of the annotation rather than its `content` attribute (which would be helpful for `Map`s). As a side-note I'd omit the `Include.ALWAYS` on the class since it's the default behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
```

Instead of

```
@JsonInclude(content=Include.NON_NULL)
```

Works. Thanks @Aaron.